# How do I handle whitespace in filenames in a for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have a file called 'removethese' who's contents looks like this:

```
./test_dir/file1
./test_dir/file2
./test_dir/file 3test
./test_dir/file4 test
```

I'm trying to remove each one of them in a for loop like this:

```
for file in `cat removelist`; do rm -v "$file"; done
```

The whitespace in the filenames seems to mess this up.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in bash:

```
 while read item; do rm "$item"; done < removelist
```

i.e. if the files have the correct properties etc.